# Moving button in screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have a feature on our website to prove us that the user is an actual human.

Here is how it's working.

After registering a button is shown and told to users to click on it ro prove that you are a human.

Once being mouseovered it start to move randomly all over the screen.

We use jquery to do this.

The main problem is that users are stopping javascript on their browser or edit the js with browser developer.

Some have created html forms to bypass this (yes we have csrf protection on all our forms they simply edit their form to the new csrf values)

This cheat is causing us to loose money.

We would appreciate help..

Best regards

P.S: We are familiar with captcha(google, solvemdia etc etc) but our proving system has to be this

Comment: why not using captcha ?

Comment: Ya, the new recaptcha?  Anyway, this check cannot be done only client side, you need some algo to check it server side

Comment: `We are familiar with captcha(google, solvemdia etc etc) but our proving system has to be this` So you just want to reinvent the wheel?! FYI, anything client side is public, so again, if you have to implement security check, this cannot be done only client side. You have to implement more complex logic server side using e.g some session/token authentification.

Comment: Translation: we came up with a human-verification system that is fundamentally flawed. People find it easy to cheat. Some people also prefer not to run our scripts, how **unfair**. Someone higher up decreed that we have to use this flawed system. Please solve our unsolvable problem for us. For free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button will have the same ID therefor it's simple for someone to programmatically click it even if it does move on the screen.

The best way you could prove that the user is human would be to use a proven method such as  a CAPTCHA(http://www.captcha.net/)

You can use the freely available reCAPTCHA(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) from Google as suggested by @A.Wolff.

Comment: More sounds like OP is looking for the new google recaptcha: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: @A.Wolff Yup, that is a good implementation that he can use. I'll append it to my answer

Comment: @nipuna777: We must use this method, we do not want captcha.

Comment: @Farshid In that case you'll have to have a check done in the backend. Because, as it was previously mentioned, everything client side is public. You can generate a new button on a random position/id using the backend. This would be relatively more difficult to crack. But still it's NOT foolproof. If at all possible, the best option would be to use a proven technology like recaptcha.

Comment: @nipuna777 check what exactly?

Comment: @Farshid Check something generated by the backend. An example would be creating some images with only one saying 'click me'. This would require   a would be cracker to use image processing to bypass your check. Which is much harder than bypassing a JS check.